# 2D-array being scanned in secondary function and main() is still able to see it

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

The below code sums two matrices successfully. If you notice: Matrix A is being scanned on a secondary function while Matrix B is being scanned in the main function. Now my question is: why `main()` is able to successfully sum both matrices, considering that A was scanned in a secondary function and I didn't pass it onto the main() function right after it was scanned. Maybe it is being passed & I am missing something about the dynamics of 2D-arrays and their pointers. Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COL 3 
#define ROW 3

int scan_the_matrix(int i, int j, int (*A)[COL]);

int main()
{

int A[ROW][COL], B[ROW][COL], SUM[ROW][COL];
int i=0, j=0;

printf("Please enter the values of your first %dx%d matrix\n", COL, ROW);
scan_the_matrix(i,j, A);

printf("Please enter the values of your second %dx%d matrix\n", COL, ROW);
  for (i = 0; i < COL; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
    {
      printf("B[%d][%d]=", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &B[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < COL; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
    {
     SUM[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < COL; ++i)
  {
   for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
   {
     printf(" %d ", SUM[i][j]);
   }
  printf("\n");
  }
return 0;
}


int scan_the_matrix(int i, int j, int (*A)[COL])
{
  for (i = 0; i < COL; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < COL; ++j)
    {
      printf("A[%d][%d]=", i, j);
      scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you use an array as a function argument, a pointer to the array is passed, it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Isn't that why you declared the parameter as a pointer?

Comment: You pass a pointer to the first element in the array `A` to the `scan_the_matrix` function. This pointer can be used to access all elements (and beyond) of the array. The call `scan_the_matrix(i,j, A)` is equivalent to `scan_the_matrix(i,j, &A[0])`.

Comment: I actually understood it now with your comments @Barmar, someprogrammerdude — thank you! The above code I pasted serves its purpose and it was just me not wrapping my head around how pointers behave. Thank you!

Comment: Why `for (i = 0; i < COL; ++i)`, not `for (i = 0; i < ROW; ++i)`?